# recursive SQL in oracle SQL Developer crash Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper, oracle-golden-gate

We have got a critical oracle error

And we are not sure what is the Developer submitted SQL causes this ?

It seems SQL Developer or Oracle stand-by is having a side effect ?

Developer allows to use the production stand-by to issue read-only SQL.

That's what the DBA tells us

"Looks like this was a recursive SQL from Sql developer session which was unable to parse and LGWR was stuck on this ."

Can someone explain how this can happen ?

```
SELECT 'COLUMN' type, owner, table_name object_name, column_name, column_id, data_type 

FROM sys.all_tab_cols 

WHERE hidden_column = 'NO' and rownum <=50 and owner = :1 and table_name = :2 and column_name like :3 union all 

SELECT 'COLUMN' type, owner, table_name object_name, column_name, column_id, data_type 

FROM sys.all_tab_cols 

WHERE hidden_column = 'NO' and rownum <=50 and owner = :4 and table_name = :5 and column_name like :6 union all 

SELECT 'COLUMN' type, owner, table_name object_name, column_name, column_id, data_type 

FROM sys.all_tab_cols 

WHERE hidden_column = 'NO' and rownum <=50 and owner = :7 and table_name = :8 and column_name like :9 union all 

SELECT 'COLUMN' type, owner, table_name object_name, column_name, column_id, data_type 

FROM sys.all_tab_cols 

WHERE hidden_column = 'NO' and rownum <=50 and owner = :10 and table_name = :11 and column_name like :12 union all 

SELECT 'COLUMN' type, owner, table_name object_name, column_name, column_id, data_type 

FROM sys.all_tab_cols 

WHERE hidden_column = 'NO' and rownum <=50 and owner = :13 and table_name = :14 and column_name like :15 union all 

SELECT 'COLUMN' type, owner, table_name object_name, column_name, column_id, data_type 

FROM sys.all_tab_cols 

WHERE hidden_column = 'NO' and rownum <=50 and owner = :16 and table_name = :17 and column_name like :18 union all 

SELECT 'COLUMN' type, owner, table_name object_name, column_name, column_id, data_type 

FROM sys.all_tab_cols 

WHERE hidden_column = 'NO' and rownum <=50 and owner = :19 and table_name = :20 and column_name like :21 union all 

SELECT 'COLUMN' type, owner, table_name object_name, column_name, column_id, data_type 

FROM sys.all_tab_cols 

WHERE hidden_column = 'NO' and rownum <=50 and owner = :22 and table_name = :23 and column_name like :24 union all 

SELECT 'COLUMN' type, owner, table_name object_name, column_name, column_id, data_type 

FROM sys.all_tab_cols 

WHERE hidden_column = 'NO' and rownum <=50 and owner = :25 and table_name = :26 and column_name like :27 union all 

SELECT 'COLUMN' type, owner, table_name object_name, column_name, column_id, data_type 

FROM sys.all_tab_cols 

WHERE hidden_column = 'NO' and rownum <=50 and owner = :28 and table_name = :29 and column_name like :30 union all 

SELECT 'COLUMN' type, owner, table_name object_name, column_name, column_id, data_type
```

Comment: Rational Databases like Sql server and oracle `officially` do not support recursive procedures.

Comment: What is the actual error? You can see all the sql that sql developer issues in the Log panel, Statements box. This isn't recursive sql... We run this directly when browsing tables.

Comment: @MR.AF . . . Can you find a reference for that comment?  I have no problem with stored procedures that call themselves:  https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=9714895b4cd78c4ec5dbaac9abe3ffd7.

Comment: @GordonLinoff 1-https://www.researchgate.net/publication/221318238_Recursive_Query_Facilities_in_Relational_Databases_A_Survey 2-https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL:1999 3-https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hierarchical_and_recursive_queries_in_SQL

Comment: @GordonLinoff you are correct that we can implement recursion in SQL but I mean that using recursion is not a good idea in SQL